# Xamarin.Forms Collection View

Tags: c#, xamarin, uicollectionview, gallery, xamarin.forms

What would be the best way to go about re-creating a view like iOS' UICollectionView in Xamarin.Forms?  I need it to be cross platform.  The two options i thought of right off the bat are using Xamarin.Forms.Grid, and Xamarin.Forms.Listview (Customizing the cells to have 3 "Columns"). Any other ideas or input? This is going to be used for an image gallery by the way.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code to use the RelativeLayout to behave like a StackPanel

```
public class MyContentPage : ContentPage
{
    public MyContentPage()
    {
        var layout = new RelativeLayout();

        var box1 = new ContentView
        {
            BackgroundColor = Color.Gray,
            Content = new Label
            {
                Text = "0"
            }
        };

        double padding = 10;
        layout.Children.Add( box1, () => new Rectangle(((layout.Width + padding) % 60) / 2, padding, 50, 50));

        var last = box1;
        for (int i = 0; i < 200; i++)
        {
            var relativeTo = last; // local copy
            var box = new ContentView
            {
                BackgroundColor = Color.Gray,
                Content = new Label
                {
                    Text = (i + 1).ToString()
                }
            };

            Func<View, bool> pastBounds = view => relativeTo.Bounds.Right + padding + view.Width > layout.Width;
            layout.Children.Add(box, () => new Rectangle(pastBounds(relativeTo) ? box1.X : relativeTo.Bounds.Right + padding,
                       pastBounds(relativeTo) ? relativeTo.Bounds.Bottom + padding : relativeTo.Y,
                       relativeTo.Width,
                       relativeTo.Height));

            last = box;
        }

        Content = new ScrollView { Content = layout, Padding = new Thickness(6) };
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a clever solution, but how does this handle recycling/virtualization of cells?